# TCL / TK backup firewall

Tags: shell, terminal, sh, expect

I have a question. I am trying to make a backup of some Firewall that are in cluster mode, I can do the backup, but the problem arises when I change the prompt and it is when it does not work.

My question is, how can I put the variable so that each time I pick up the different message it keeps working?

```
[?1034h\[root@FW1-04:Standby:Disconnected\]]0;FW1-04 config # "
[?1060h\[root@FW1-03:Standby:Disconnected\]]0;FW1-03 config # "
```

Greetings and thank you

My code would be like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECQXt.jpg)

Comment: #!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "sshpass -p rangerJump87 ssh root@124.24.2.2"
expect -exact "sshpass -p rangerJump87 ssh root@124.24.2.2"
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "\r
[?1034h\[root@FW1-04:Standby:Disconnected\]]0;FW1-04 config # "

Comment: Try setting `env(TERM)` to `dumb` in your Expect script before doing the `spawn`. Should cut out at least some of the annoying stuff…

Comment: Hello, I do not understand the answer, you could indicate me. My fault or that I think is is here.                                                                                     
 [?1034h\[root@FW1-04:Standby:Disconnected\]]0;FW1-04 config # "

Answer (score 0):

Solved part of the problem and could make a backup but not at the level you want, the way to solve it has been like this.

#!/bin/bash

HOST="124.24.2.2"

USER="root"

PASS="rangerJump87"

CMD=$@

VAR=$(expect -c "

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST $CMD

match_max 100000

expect \"*?assword:*\"

send -- \"$PASS\r\"

send -- \"\r\"

send -- \"\r\"

expect eof

")

echo "==============="

"echo "$VAR"

Execute  ./f-5.sh "tmsh show running-config" > testf5.text

This way I can make a backup but, I need to make a backup to another level and it is with the commands "imish" and "enable", can you tell me how I can upload it? . Greetings and thank you